# How do you render ContentChildren elements in an ng-template?

Tags: angular

Given a component, I wish to wrap the rendered child elements in it.

How is this possible in angular2?

For example, I have this component:

```
export class InnerTestComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChildren('link') contents: QueryList<ElementRef>;
}
```

and this template:

```
<div>
  <h3>Children test: {{ contents.length }} to render</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let child of contents">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="someTemplateName; context: {child: child}">
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #someTemplateName let-child="child">
  <h3>Child</h3>
  <div>
    {{ child }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And when I call:

```
<templates-inner-test>
  <a #link href="#">Test1</a>
  <a #link href="#">Test2</a>
</templates-inner-test>
```

I get:

```
<templates-inner-test>
<div>
  <h3>Children test: 2 to render</h3>
  <h3>Child</h3>
  <div>
    [object Object] <--- WRONG
  </div>
  </div><div>
  <h3>Child</h3>
  <div>
    [object Object] <--- WRONG
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</templates-inner-test>
```

When what I want is:

```
<h3>Child</h3>
<div>
  <a href="#">Test1</a>
</div>
<h3>Child</h3>
<div>
  <a href="#">Test2</a>
</div>
```

I appreciate rendering an `ElementRef` in `{{ ... }}` simply executes `toString()` on it, but what should I be doing instead?

I would like to also specifically point out that the solutions floating around in various places to use the `<ng-content select="child"></ng-content>` flat out don't work. That just renders an empty `<div>`.

Comment: No sure about what you are trying to achieve here put it sounds like Dynamic Component there is a chapter in the doc about it https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `contents` is a list `ElementRef`, and you are looping through it, `child` is a ElementRef, so you probably need to use `child.nativeElement.innerHTML`.

But you definitely need to use `DomSanitizer` here, with it you could probably do the following

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtml implements PipeTransform  {
    constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
    transform(style) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);   
    }
}
```

Then you could

```
<ng-template #someTemplateName let-child="child">
    <h3>Child</h3>
    <div [innerHTML]="child.nativeElement.innerHTML | safeHtml" ></div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: it's usually not a good idea to bypass security even when you know what you are doing. And angular provide api to do it safely.